# Посчитать строковое выражение с математическими функциями используя C# (Expression Evaluator)

Tags: c#, строки, float, eval, expressions

Всем привет!

Есть ли способ посчитать строковое выражение с математическими функциями используя C# (***без использования сторонних решений и библиотек***)?

Пример счёта строкового выражение с математическими функциями:

```
string test_s_expression = "5 + sin(0.1 * 8) - cos(0.5 - (3/4))";
ExpressionEvaluator EE = new ExpressionEvaluator();
float results = EE.Eval(test_s_expression);
```

P.S. Я делаю iOS приложение на движке Unity, поэтому при билле на iOS код должен работать.

Comment: вероятно парсить строку и использовать стандартную библиотеку Math?

Answer (score 2):

Нужен парсинг строки. Ответ получился несколько больше чем я ожидал, весьма корявым, но для примера Вам надеюсь подойдет:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
class Program
{       
    public static float Eval(string expres)
    {
        string[] number = expres.Split("+-*/sincostg()".ToCharArray());
        var listNumber = new List<string>();

        foreach (var item in number)
        {
            if(!item.Equals("") && !item.Equals(" "))
            {
                listNumber.Add(item);
            }
        }
        number = listNumber.ToArray();

        float result = Convert.ToSingle(number[0]);            
        string[] operation = expres.Split("0123456789()".ToCharArray());

        listNumber.Clear();
        foreach (var item in operation)
        {
            if (!item.Equals("") && !item.Equals(" "))
            {
                listNumber.Add(item);
            }
        }
        operation = listNumber.ToArray();

        for(int i = 0; i < operation.Length; i++)
        {
            if(!operation[i].Equals("+") && !operation[i].Equals("-") 
                && !operation[i].Equals("*") && !operation[i].Equals("/"))
            {
                operation[i] =
                    operation[i].Remove(0, 3);
            }
        }

        for (int i = 0; i < operation.Length; i++)
        {
            if (operation[i].Equals("+"))
            {
                result += Convert.ToSingle(number[i]);
            }
            if (operation[i].Equals("-"))
            {
                result -= Convert.ToSingle(number[i]);
            }
            if (operation[i].Equals("*"))
            {
                result *= Convert.ToSingle(number[i]);
            }
            if (operation[i].Equals("/"))
            {
                result /= Convert.ToSingle(number[i]);
            }
            if (operation[i].Equals("sin"))
            {
                if ((i != 0) && operation[i - 1].Equals("+"))
                {
                    result += (float)Math.Sin(Convert.ToSingle(number[i]));
                }
                if ((i != 0) && operation[i - 1].Equals("-"))
                {
                    result -= (float)Math.Sin(Convert.ToSingle(number[i]));
                }
                if ((i != 0) && operation[i - 1].Equals("*"))
                {
                    result *= (float)Math.Sin(Convert.ToSingle(number[i]));
                }
                if ((i != 0) && operation[i - 1].Equals("/"))
                {
                    result /= (float)Math.Sin(Convert.ToSingle(number[i]));
                }
                if(i == 0)
                {
                    result = (float)Math.Sin(Convert.ToSingle(number[i]));
                }
            }
            if (operation[i].Equals("cos"))
            {
                if ((i != 0) && operation[i - 1].Equals("+"))
                {
                    result += (float)Math.Cos(Convert.ToSingle(number[i]));
                }
                if ((i != 0) && operation[i - 1].Equals("-"))
                {
                    result -= (float)Math.Cos(Convert.ToSingle(number[i]));
                }
                if ((i != 0) && operation[i - 1].Equals("*"))
                {
                    result *= (float)Math.Cos(Convert.ToSingle(number[i]));
                }
                if ((i != 0) && operation[i - 1].Equals("/"))
                {
                    result /= (float)Math.Cos(Convert.ToSingle(number[i]));
                }
                if (i == 0)
                {
                    result = (float)Math.Cos(Convert.ToSingle(number[i]));
                }
            }
            if (operation[i].Equals("tg"))
            {
                if ((i != 0) && operation[i - 1].Equals("+"))
                {
                    result += (float)Math.Tan(Convert.ToSingle(number[i]));
                }
                if ((i != 0) && operation[i - 1].Equals("-"))
                {
                    result -= (float)Math.Tan(Convert.ToSingle(number[i]));
                }
                if ((i != 0) && operation[i - 1].Equals("*"))
                {
                    result *= (float)Math.Tan(Convert.ToSingle(number[i]));
                }
                if ((i != 0) && operation[i - 1].Equals("/"))
                {
                    result /= (float)Math.Tan(Convert.ToSingle(number[i]));
                }
                if (i == 0)
                {
                    result = (float)Math.Tan(Convert.ToSingle(number[i]));
                }
            }
        }
        return result;
    }

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(Eval("5+5-3 * sin(11) - cos(55) / tg(20)"));
        Console.Read();
    }
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

У кода вверху второе число уравнения всегда равно первому, что бы вы не ввели

using System.Data;

```
 public static double Evaluate(string expression)
    {
        DataTable table = new DataTable();
        table.Columns.Add("expression", typeof(string), expression);
        DataRow row = table.NewRow();
        table.Rows.Add(row);
        return double.Parse((string)row["expression"]);
    }
```

Вот эта тема будет работать, не забудьте про либу